# re-iterate over and over rather than once in soup

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I keep re-iterating over this code. I'm keen to **scrape** all past results data from this site yet i keep looping over one by one?

for example race_number printed goes 1, 1,2, 1,2,3 etc etc

End goal is to full all list with data and panda it out to look at results and trends.

```
import requests
import csv
import os
import numpy
import pandas

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with requests.Session() as s:
    webpage_response = s.get('http://www.harness.org.au/racing/fields/race-fields/?mc=SW010420')
    soup = bs(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")
    #soup1 = soup.select('.content')
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'forPrint'})
    race_number = []
    race_name = []
    race_title = []
    race_distance = []
    place = []
    horse_name = []
    Prizemoney = []
    Row = []
    horse_number = []
    Trainer = []
    Driver = []
    Margin = []
    Starting_odds = []
    Stewards_comments = []
    Scratching = []
    Track_Rating = []
    Gross_Time = []
    Mile_Rate = []
    Lead_Time = []
    First_Quarter = []
    Second_Quarter = []
    Third_Quarter = []
    Fourth_Quarter = []

    for race in results:
        race_number1 = race.find(class_='raceNumber').get_text()
        race_number.append(race_number1)
        race_name1 = race.find(class_='raceTitle').get_text()
        race_name.append(race_name1)
        race_title1 = race.find(class_='raceInformation').get_text(strip=True)
        race_title.append(race_title1)
        race_distance1 = race.find(class_='distance').get_text()
        race_distance.append(race_distance1)
```

Need help fixing iteration over and over, and what is the next best move to look at table data rather than headers above?
Cheers

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: to get tables from html, look up pandas `.read_html()`. and also, this question is pretty unclear. What are you exactly trying to achieve, what do you mean it prints, 1,2,3, 1,2,3. Lastly, to get the historical data, it appears you are going to need to iterate one by one, as I don't see an api to get all the data in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the output you are expecting:

```
import requests
import csv
import os
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import html

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with requests.Session() as s:
    webpage_response = s.get('http://www.harness.org.au/racing/fields/race-fields/?mc=SW010420')
    soup = bs(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")
    #soup1 = soup.select('.content')
    data = {}
    data["raceNumber"] = [ i['rowspan'] for i in soup.find_all("td", {"class": "raceNumber", "rowspan": True})]
    data["raceTitle"] = [ i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.find_all("td", {"class": "raceTitle"})]
    data["raceInformation"] = [ i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.find_all("td", {"class": "raceInformation"})]
    data["distance"] = [ i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.find_all("td", {"class": "distance"})]
    print(data)

    data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(data_frame)
##    Output
##      raceNumber                             raceTitle                                    raceInformation distance
##0          3                      PREMIX KING PACE  $4,500\n\t\t\t\t\t4YO and older.\n\t\t\t\t\tNR...    1785M
##1          3                 GATEWAY SECURITY PACE  $7,000\n\t\t\t\t\t4YO and older.\n\t\t\t\t\tNR...    2180M
##2          3                 PERRY'S FOOTWEAR TROT  $7,000\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\tNR 46 to 55.\n\t...    2180M
##3          3           DELAHUNTY PLUMBING 3YO TROT  $7,000\n\t\t\t\t\t3YO.\n\t\t\t\t\tNR 46 to 52....    2180M
##4          3  RAYNER'S FRUIT & VEGETABLES 3YO PACE  $7,000\n\t\t\t\t\t3YO.\n\t\t\t\t\tNR 48 to 56....    2180M
##5          3                 KAYE MATTHEWS TRIBUTE  $9,000\n\t\t\t\t\t4YO and older.\n\t\t\t\t\tNR...    2180M
##6          3                   TALQUIST TREES PACE  $7,000\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\tNR 62 to 73.\n\t...    2180M
##7          3            WEEKLY ADVERTISER 3WM PACE  $7,000\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\tNR 56 to 61.\n\t...    1785M
```

Comment: thats perfect, but i want what you have printed as the heading, then i want to re-iterate over tab data for each heading printed above- 

so if i go with your code and then a for loop over td this doesnt seem to re-iterate over the td or heading im after

Comment: Just add the headings in a list and later you can iterate using the list of headings.

Comment: But you should have in which part the given parameter is there like `dev` or `td`

Comment: You need to specify the headings in one list and corresponding parameter(td or th) in other list

Comment: yes so headings in a list and then re-iterate over td

Comment: so its should be for loop with list to store headings similar to above and then a for loop against headers to get td after?

Comment: No need of for loop for storing headings and td, you can directly specify a list `headings=["raceNumber", "raceTitle"]`.